# How to use first time generated randomly matrix?

Tags: matrix, random, table, random-process

I'm trying to solve one (very little) problem. :)
I've generated 3x3 randomly matrix with

`V[i_, j_] := Table[RandomInteger[{-10i, 10j}], {3}, {3}]`;

Now I want to use, for example, matrix `V[2,2]` in the next 3-4 steps, but every time it generate new randomly matrix. I need **exactly** randomly matrix generated first time. xD

Comment: Use [`SeedRandom`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) to make random numbers repeatable

Comment: I'm trying but I'm not succeeding.

Comment: You don't need a `Table`, for a 3x3 matrix use `RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}]`

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious ... the lhs and 'assignment', ie `V[i_,j_] :=` are part of a common idiom to define a function in *Mathematica*.  In this case the function generates a new random matrix each time it is called, exactly the behaviour observed. Check, if you are not sure, the difference between `=` and `:=`.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for memoization:

```
V[i_, j_] := V[i, j] = Table[RandomInteger[{-10 i, 10 j}], {3}, {3}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call your function once to generate the matrix, and store the result in a different variable...

```
v[i_, j_] := RandomInteger[{-10 i, 10 j}, {3, 3}]
mymat = v[2, 2]
```

Then use `mymat` in subsequent steps.